# How to get the commit author name for Google Cloud Build on github commits

Tags: google-cloud-build

Is it possible to get the commit author name in Google Cloud Build Github triggers.

I followed this https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configure-third-party-notifications and  https://thecloudfunction.com/blog/slack-notifications-cloud-build/ to set it up.

All the notifications are working fine.

I just want to show the name/email of the person who committed the code which does seem to be available in the build object.

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like this info is not yet available. There is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/144151357) which I recommend you to 'star' to receive notifications.